# Having trouble with node-sqlserver in node.js

Tags: sql-server-2008, node.js

I am having trouble connecting to a database on a computer on my network using node-sqlserver by Microsoft in node.js.  I am using sql server 2008 on a windows 2008 server.  I am remotely running my node.js on different machine within the same domain.  I think the issue has to do with the connection string.

```
var sql = require('node-sqlserver');
var conn_str = 'Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=(win08-srv);Database=DB;Trusted_Connection={Yes}';
```

Also, there should be a user name and password to get into the Database, however this wasn't in the example connection string from the node module.

```
//open the DB connection
sql.open(conn_str, function (err, conn) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error opening the connection!");
    return;
    } else {
        console.log('Connection successful!');
        return;
    }
});
```

Always results in printing `Error opening the connection!` when run.

Comment: Does your sql server allow remote connections? Does win08-srv resolve?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  How can I check that win08-srv resolves?  I added it to my connections in the ODBC settings on the machine running node.js and the connection there was successful.

Comment: Just see if you can ping it. If that resolves, make sure the SQL server is configured to accept remote connections. If that still doesn't work, check that you have the SQL Server Native Access Client installed and that it's the right version (you have 10.0, 11.0 also exists). If that doesn't help, check that the database (DB) is correct. After that, I have no ideas left :)

Comment: still no luck.  how can I change the user and password in the connection string

Comment: Here's an example conn_str, with more options set. Edit to your wishes (and make sure port, encryption, etc. are set correctly too): 
var conn_str = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=tcp:{win08-srv},1433;Database={DB};Uid={username};Pwd={password};Encrypt=yes;Connection Timeout=30;";

Comment: You know what?  That was it!  Thanks so much.  The issue was that I had '(' ')' around the server name and I didnt speciy the user and password.  It was user windows authentication instead.  As a side note, if you use trusted connection, then the server will override the username and password and just use the windows authentication no matter what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I was able to connect was through changing my connect string.  I had to change it to say `Trusted_Connection{No}` and then supply login credentials.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. The first thing you need to do in order to diagnose the problem is change the sample code as bellow:

```
sql.open(conn_str, function (err, conn) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error opening the connection! Error was: " + err);
    return;
}
```

Once I did the above, I got a bit more information on the error. My error was:

```
"Error opening the connection! Error: IM002: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"
```

This basically means you've specified the wrong driver in the connection string. I solved my issue by changing the driver version from 11.0 to 10.0. You can see what drivers are installed locally (if you're on windows, which I assume you are) by going to:

Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Data Sources (ODBC) > Drivers(tab).

Look for the SQL Server Native Client and see the version number. If you don't have this driver installed, you'll need to download it.

Comment: ergh! I can't believe that's all it was, changing 11 to 10 fixed it for me as well.

Comment: Simple fixes are always the best though :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this connection string to allow you to specify a user name and password combination obviously adapt for your settings

var conn_str = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=TEXAS;Database=NodeMassive;Uid=WebDev;Pwd=developer1;";